# How to keep a getSelection active using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change font-size of the selected text in my div by clicking a button but when I press my button i lose the highlight/selection. How can I keep the text highlighted/selected while I also press my button.

```js
    function sizeup(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var selectedText = document.getSelection();
        //please compelete after here
        
    }
```

```html
<!--Html here-->
<div contenteditable="true" style="height:200px;">
<button onclick="sizeup(event)">SIZEUP</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the element by its ID and then manipulate the font-size :

```js
function changeFontSize() {
    var selectedText = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
      selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
      var newContent = document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML.replace(selectedText, '<span style="font-size:30px;">'+selectedText+'</span>');
      document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = newContent;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" contenteditable="true" style="height:100px;">asdasd</div>
<button onclick="changeFontSize()">SIZEUP</button>
```

Comment: No! that way font-size increases for all the text I need only some part of it that I select to get increased.

Comment: I have edited the code you can check it but there is a catch in this if you select a particular text for example "a" which is at the end of the string and if there is another "a" which is in front then it will resize the front one. I hope you will get few ideas now about how you can have a approach for these kind of questions.

Comment: This is near but the problem is still there.. i need the selection not to get deselected afetr performing the function

Comment: There is one ::selection property in css i initially thought that can be used here but when i tried that only colors were getting changed not the font-size.